# jupyter nternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter

I installed anaconda 3.7 on windows (following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPq6NIboLSc) and then tried to run a code using tensorflow (https://github.com/DeepRNN/image_captioning) from jupyter notebook but I'm getting:

> InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

When looking for my cuda version:

## > where cudnn*

C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\gputest\Library\bin\cudnn64_7.dll

```
 (gputest) C:\windows\system32>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.13.1
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\...\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, keras-applications, grpcio, gast, six, tensorboard, keras-preprocessing, termcolor, absl-py, astor, protobuf, wheel, tensorflow-estimator
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Updating the NVIDIA driver may solve your issue.
2. Maybe you have to first match your tensorflow version with your installed Cuda Toolkit 
   version like shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations)

Comment: Will try to sync versions. BTW, don't I need the windows link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows? (the one you attached is for linux/mac os)... is there a need for installing GPU Computing Toolkit (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) on my windows too or it's part of the anaconda virtual env already (I ran > conda install tensorflow-gpu)

Comment: Solved. Installing GPU on my computer solved it. (I thought it will be part of anaconda env)